# Creating active state for thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, image-gallery

I'm using a full-screen image gallery on my website, however I'm trying to style the thumbnails that allow me to navigate true the different images. The tumbnails are generated with the JS file. I managed to style them as triangle's with a normal and hover state.

My question, I want to add an ACTIVE to this that shows a black triangle when that certain images is displayed. How can I do this?

**JS file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slider;
    var images = [
        "images/productie/1.jpg",
        "images/productie/2.jpg",
        "images/productie/3.jpg",
        "images/productie/4.jpg",
        "images/productie/5.jpg"
    ];
    var index = 0;
    var transitionSpeed = 500;
    var imageIntervals = 5000;
    var startIntervals;
    var intervalSetTime;
    var contentOpen = false;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            controls: false,
            pause: imageIntervals
        });

        for (i=0;i<=images.length - 1;i++){
            $('#thumb-container').append('<a href="javascript:goToContent('+ i +')"><img src="'+ images[i] +'?size=thumb" alt="Image '+ i +'" /></a>');
        }

        $(function() {

            $.preload(images, {
                init: function(loaded, total) {
                    $("#indicator").html("<img src='images/load.gif' />");          
                },

                loaded_all: function(loaded, total) { 
                    $('#indicator').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $('#left-side').fadeIn('slow');
                        $('#thumb-container').fadeIn('slow');

                        $.backstretch(images[index], {speed: transitionSpeed});

                        startIntervals = function (){
                            intervalSetTime = setInterval(function() {
                            index = (index >= images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
                            $.backstretch(images[index]);
                            slider.goToNextSlide()
                        }, imageIntervals)};

                        startIntervals();                   
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function goToContent(slideNum){
        clearInterval(intervalSetTime);
        index = slideNum;
        $.backstretch(images[index]);
        slider.goToSlide(slideNum);
        if (contentOpen == false){
            startIntervals();
        }
    };

    function showContent(){
        $('.content-bg').fadeIn('slow');
        clearInterval(intervalSetTime);
        contentOpen = true;
    };
    function closeContent(){
        $('.content-bg').fadeOut('slow');
        startIntervals();
        contentOpen = false;
    };
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
#thumb-container{
    display:none;
}

#thumb-container img{
    float:left;
    border:0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    margin:2px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid  #fff;
}

#thumb-container img:hover{
    float:left;
    border:0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid  #000;
    }
```

Comment: Try `#thumb-container:active img` if the #thumb-container contains only one img.

Comment: Hee Alexander, that does not work..

Comment: Ugh, so what do you mean by "ACTIVE"? `:active` is a pseudo-class applied when you activate (e.g. press a mouse button on) an element...

Comment: I mean with ACTIVE, that let's say when image number 2 is being shown, thumbnail number 2 will be highlighted with the same styling guide as the hover. So they should correspond with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered by **Shefqet Avdullau**

*Javascript*

```
var slider;
var images = [
    "IMAGES LINK",
    "IMAGES LINK",
    "IMAGES LINK"
];
var index = 0;
var transitionSpeed = 500;
var imageIntervals = 5000;
var startIntervals;
var intervalSetTime;
var contentOpen = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

    slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        controls: false,
        pause: imageIntervals
    });

    for (i=0;i<=images.length - 1;i++){
        $('#thumb-container').append('<a href="javascript:goToContent('+ i +')"><img src="'+ images[i] +'?size=thumb" alt="Image '+ i +'" /></a>');
    }

    $(function() {

        $.preload(images, {
            init: function(loaded, total) {
                $("#indicator").html("<img src='images/load.gif' />");            
            },

            loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {
                $('#indicator').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $('#left-side').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#thumb-container').fadeIn('slow');

                    /* added by Shefqet Avdullau */
                    $('#thumb-container a').removeClass('current_anchor').eq(index).addClass('current_anchor');
                    $.backstretch(images[index], {speed: transitionSpeed});

                    startIntervals = function (){
                        intervalSetTime = setInterval(function() {
                        index = (index >= images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;

                        /* added by me */
                        $('#thumb-container a').removeClass('current_anchor').eq(index).addClass('current_anchor');

                        $.backstretch(images[index]);
                        slider.goToNextSlide()
                    }, imageIntervals)};

                    startIntervals();                    
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

function goToContent(slideNum){
    clearInterval(intervalSetTime);
    index = slideNum;
    /* added by Shefqet Avdullau */
    $('#thumb-container a').removeClass('current_anchor').eq(index).addClass('current_anchor');

    $.backstretch(images[index]);
    slider.goToSlide(slideNum);
    if (contentOpen == false){
        startIntervals();
    }
};

function showContent(){
    $('.content-bg').fadeIn('slow');
    clearInterval(intervalSetTime);
    contentOpen = true;
};
function closeContent(){
    $('.content-bg').fadeOut('slow');
    startIntervals();
    contentOpen = false;
};
```

*CSS*

```
/* THUMB SECTION */

#thumb-container{
    display:none;
}

#thumb-container img{
    float:left;
    border:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin:2px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid  #fff;
}

/* added by Shefqet Avdullau */

#thumb-container a.current_anchor img,

#thumb-container img:hover,
#thumb-container img.displayed {
    float:left;
    border:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid  #6bcade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the last clarification comment on the question, I believe you should add and remove the respective CSS class (e.g. `displayed`) from the thumbnail image, using JavaScript. And modify the last rule selector to be:

```
#thumb-container img:hover, #thumb-container img.displayed
```

Comment: Alexander where can I find the class displayed?

Comment: It's a CSS class. You'll add it to the image as `imageElement.className = "displayed"`. More on this [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/)

Comment: Thank you, will look into it! Hope it will be fixed with this

Comment: Alexander I tried this: for (i=0;i<=images.length - 1;i++){
            $('#thumb-container').append('<a href="javascript:goToContent('+ i +')"><img src="'+ images[i] +'?size=thumb" alt="Image '+ i +'" imageElement.className="displayed" /></a>');}

Comment: http://www.q-international-projecten.nl/ESD_Systeemwanden/productie.html This is a link to the website Alexander.

Comment: `className` is a property on JavaScript object, so should get set from the JS code. Instead, you seem to be (a) generating `alt` attribute with the JS statement I gave; (b) trying to do this for all images rather than the "active" one. You need to set up "onclick" handlers for the thumbnail elements and update the CSS classes accordingly, which is really beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Oke, but I can not find where in the JS I need to do this. Is it possible to modify this on the code displayed above? Or do I have to dig deeper into the jQuery bxSlider v3.0 source code?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with the bxSlider, but it seems you may try plugging into the `goToContent` function above. You just need to get the associated thumbnail image element and assign it the `displayed` class (and, obviously, remove this class from the previously `displayed` element, if any).

Comment: Alex, I tried this since i'm using a # in my css. But it's not working. $('#thumb-container').append('<a href="javascript:goToContent('+ i +')" id="thumb-container img.displayed"><img src="'+ images[i] +'?size=thumb" alt="Image '+ i +'" /></a>');

Comment: `id="thumb-container img.displayed"` is wrong as you are trying to assign the class to the A element, not the IMG element. Remove "img.displayed" and use `<img src="'+ images[i] +'?size=thumb" alt="Image '+ i +'" class="displayed" />` I strongly recommend that you take at least a [quick tour](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) of CSS selectors.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the code, it works partly, because it highlights all the thumbnails. Not the one that is being shown. I guess this has to do with the ' + image[i]+ ' function? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Good. You need to actually set the `displayed` class in the `goToContent`, as I said above.

Comment: This does not work: <a href="javascript:goToContent('+ i +')" class="displayed">